# How to subscript x_n+1 in microsoft word equation

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing my report and this equation is quite tricky to write which has 'x' and in subscript 'n+1'. I try to do x_n+1 inside equation, but this doesn't work. How to I subscript sequence of letters in a same line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add subscripts using the 'add subscript' tool'. It'll add blank boxes that you can fill with 'x' and 'n+1'

[image]

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: @john no need for a shortcut. `x_(n+1)` works much faster

Answer (score 2):

Just write in the following way in the equation editor

```
x_(n+1)
```

Comment: remember to press space so that the equation will be formatted properly